# Is "wiliness" a word?

Tags: british-english, vocabulary, dictionaries

I am wondering whether *wiliness* is a legit/valid word.  Google Translate seems to translate it properly, and https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wiliness and [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wiliness#:~:text=Noun,deceitful%20cleverness%20or%20shrewdness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wiliness#:%7E:text=Noun,deceitful%20cleverness%20or%20shrewdness) also have it within their database. However, when I look to other dictionaries e.g., https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=wiliness, they do not find anything.

Any suggestions for rigorous online tools that I could find the answer for these and similar questions?

**edit:**
To be more precise on what I meant, I am trying to access the legitimacy of the following sentence:

**"His wiliness to help his peers with assignments also demonstrated to me how strongly he dominates the learned content"**

PS: I did not mean to write **willingness**.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Some dictionaries include more words than others. But whether a word is in a dictionary is not a test for whether it's a word. If you use it and somebody understands it, it's a word. The same for if they use it and you understand it. Dictionaries are just notes; the words are in the behavior.

Comment: Ask Wile E. Coyote.

Comment: Assuming you get the go-ahead here for *wiliness*, you need to modify... *His wiliness to help his peers...*  →  *His wiliness in helping his peers...*

Answer (score 2):

Oxford English Dictionary online:

> wiliness, n.    **The quality or character of being wily; craftiness, cunning, guile.**
>
> 1878   P. Bayne Chief Actors in the Puritan Revolution. iii. 81   *He had the wariness and wiliness of the cat.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the intended sentence I am about to write. 
Would that make sense to you? I want to use 'wiliness' in the sense of "cunning"

Answer (score 2):

Whether something "is a legit word" is not a question one can answer with a dictionary. As you note, different dictionaries will give you different answers, and many words (e.g. recently-coined slang) aren't in dictionaries at all.

The question is: will your audience understand it? [Google Books has plenty of recent uses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wiliness%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1989,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), so other authors seem to assume it is intelligible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the intended sentence I am about to write. 
Would that make sense to you? I want to use 'wiliness' in the sense of "cunning"